# What should we do with the Steam Monster Game questions?

Tags: discussion

This year's Steam summer sale is drawing to a close.  This year, it brought us the [steam-monster-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-monster-game), and with it, several questions regarding that game.

Now with the sale ending, it's unlikely any of us will ever be able to play it again.

What should we do with all of the [steam-monster-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-monster-game) questions that have cropped up?  Should we just leave them alone and do nothing?  Perform some type of cleanup?  Do an historic lock on them?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We leave them. There's no need to do a historical lock on them. We've dealt with this sort of thing in the past with tags like [stack-egg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-egg) and Google Doodles among others. Even though it is a game that is no longer available, we leave those questions as they are.

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine that anyone would try to play Steam Monster Clicker past the Summer Sale...but then I also didn't think Clicker games would take off, and look where we are now.  Thank you for the answer, and for correctly marking this a dupe.